Dynamic colors not working on Samsung Galaxy A55
I'm using android studio with a jetpack compose project and the dynamic color for the button is working for the pixel 8 emulated but not for my physical Samsung galaxy a55. Any reason why?
MainActivity Code:
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        enableEdgeToEdge()
        setContent {
            DynamicColorsTestTheme {
                Scaffold(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) { innerPadding ->
                    Button(
                        onClick = { /*TODO*/ },
                        colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(
                            containerColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary,
                        ),
                        modifier = Modifier.padding(innerPadding),
                        ) {
                        Text(
                            text = "Button",
                            color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onBackground,
                        )
                   }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

Theme code:
private val DarkColorScheme = darkColorScheme(
    primary = Purple80,
    secondary = PurpleGrey80,
    tertiary = Pink80
)

private val LightColorScheme = lightColorScheme(
    primary = Purple40,
    secondary = PurpleGrey40,
    tertiary = Pink40
)

@Composable
fun DynamicColorsTestTheme(
    darkTheme: Boolean = isSystemInDarkTheme(),
    // Dynamic color is available on Android 12+
    dynamicColor: Boolean = true,
    content: @Composable () -> Unit
) {
    val colorScheme = when {
        dynamicColor && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S -> {
            val context = LocalContext.current
            if (darkTheme) dynamicDarkColorScheme(context) else dynamicLightColorScheme(context)
        }

        darkTheme -> DarkColorScheme
        else -> LightColorScheme
    }

    MaterialTheme(
        colorScheme = colorScheme,
        typography = Typography,
        content = content
    )
}

I tried to change the colors for my Samsung and clear data and cache but nothing worked.

Please {edit] and provide DynamicColorsTestTheme. Also, what Android version runs on the A55?

@tyg My A55 runs android version 14 and here is my DynamicColorsTestTheme it is on a pastebin since it is too long to paste it here: https://pastebin.com/iZsgEwYj

Please [edit] your question and put the theme there. Links to external sites are not sufficient for necessary information because links may break. Please use a [code block] to properly format your code and also fix the formatting of your existing code.

@tyg oh ok I fixed it now.
